# qliksense rest api connection to get data out of qliksense

Tags: rest, qliksense

I want to get list of documents available in  Qlik sense using rest api. I am trying to use the api url `https://url/api/v1/apps/docs` to get the list of documents

But this is not working. Is the url correct in getting the documents in qliksense?

Where can I find the details on the url for getting the docs? I have checked the Qlik website for rest documentation but could not get the details what I am looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your use case is but will recommend using [Qlik Repository Service API](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/May2021/Subsystems/RepositoryServiceAPI/Content/Sense_RepositoryServiceAPI/RepositoryServiceAPI-Introduction.htm) to get list of the apps. The url in your question looks like an [Engine REST API](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/April2020/APIs/QIXAPI/index.html?page=12) endpoints but its non-existing in the endpoints list.

Repositository API is a wrapper around the internal PostgreSQL database, which contains all the metadata (list of apps, streams, extensions etc).

List with all Repository API methods can be found at [Qlik QRS API reference](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/November2021/APIs/RepositoryServiceAPI/index.html?page=726) page.

The Repository API supports few authentication methods

- certificates (when using in server-to-server communication. aka backend)
- JWT
- Header
- Session cookie (from the browser)

Have a look at the examples how to test the responses with [Postman](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/May2021/Subsystems/RepositoryServiceAPI/Content/Sense_RepositoryServiceAPI/RepositoryServiceAPI-Example-Connect-Postman.htm) (few other examples are available there - `Powershell`, `Node.JS`, `cURL` etc.)